# Greedy Change-Making Algorithm in matlab

Tags: matlab, dynamic-programming

let us suppose we have following  array

```
a=[9 15 10 7 8  6];
n=43;
```

what i want is to choose several  numbers with greedy property(  also repeated numbers possible are ) whose sum  gives  us 43, for instance

```
 15 15 9 7
```

and i have implemented following code

```
 function total=change_making(a,n)
        % n total number of coints  to make
        % a array  of coints
        total=0;
        while (total+max(a))<=n
            total=total+max(a);
               fprintf('% d ',max(a));
              if (total+max(a))>n
            while (total+max(a))>n
           a(find(a==max(a)))=[];% ti remove  maximum array
            end


              end

        end

        end
```

but when i applied to the given input, i got

```
total=change_making(a,n)
 15  15  10 
total =

    40
```

of course we dont have  exactly 43, so one of approach will be  to check if  n-total will be less then  all  element of  a, which means

```
all(a)>(n-total)
```

but i am not sure if this will work for any case, so what will be best approach? thanks in advance

Comment: I think you mean sum=46, not 43. Is that correct?

Comment: why 46 ? what i wanted  was to select sum of whose would be 43